# Minecraft ComputerCraft Turtles require statement not working

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I have been writing a lot of turtle programs lately and find that I am constantly rewriting the same functions. I would like to put all these functions into their own file and then include them at the top of my other turtle programs. Looking through the lua documentation it seems I need to use `require`. However I can't seem to get it to work. Here is a basic example I tried:

program1:

```
 print("Hello World")
```

program2

```
require program1
```

This resulted in the following error:

> ```
> bios:366: [string "program2"]:1: '=' expected
> ```

I then tried setting the package path to the current directory before making the require statement like this:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';./?.lua;'
```

That also didn't work. It seem that turtles don't use the same syntax as lua for the require statement (if they support it at all)

Is there a way to do something like this with the turtles? If it is using 'require' then what is the proper syntax? (I don't have access to the files of the server I play on so simply editing them is not an option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is a function; you need to call it using function syntax:

```
require("foo")
-- or
require "foo"
```

...but it doesn't look like ComputerCraft supports the `require` function. Try `os.loadAPI("path/to/file")`.

(Dear developers wanting to sandbox Lua: [`require` supports configuring how it loads modules](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require); please use that instead of replacing `require`!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `program1` in quotes:

```
require "program1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but I did try that and it gave this error: (program1:1: attempt to call nil) which I assume just means the require failed.

Comment: This means `require` is not available in the ComputerCraft environment. See @ColonelThirtyTwo's answer for the alternative.